# Dropdown value not changing on page reload in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using DropdownList in my aspx page.

When I bind the first time it shows the correct selected value, but when I change the value through another aspx page and refresh this parent page, the value does not change in the drop-down, it still remains same.

```
dropdownList1.DataSource = dt;  
dropdownList1.DataBind();
dropdownList1.ClearSelection();
dropdownList1.Items.FindByText("some value").Selected = true;
```

On re-loading the aspx page, although the selected value of dropdownlist has changed but it dos not get affected in the dropdown. What could be the solution to this problem.

Any help is appreciable ...

Comment: dont work with text....

Comment: Please suggest me any other alternative for "text"

Comment: this code execute on page load?

Comment: `dropdownList1.SelectedValue="myIdWhichRepresents_some_value"`

Comment: @AnantDabhi: yes.. code execute on page load..

Comment: @RoyiNamir : that way of selecting is also not working..

Comment: then put this code in `IsPostback==false` block

Answer (score 0):

try to set selected value like below...

```
ddl.SelectedValue = ddl.Items.FindByText(your text).Value;
```

Comment: Use breakpoint and see whether the session variable is null or empty.

Comment: @Rajesh: Session variable exactly working fine,, giving required value

Comment: ddl.SelectedValue = ddl.Items.FindByText(your text).Value;
How are you using session value. Just to know how you handling the session value

Answer (score 0):

On close of pop-up window, we need to execute the following javascript function as follows...

> function closePopUp()  { 
>             window.opener.ReloadParentPage();
>         }
>
> function ReloadParentPage() {
>               popupWindow.close();
>               var path = window.location.href.split("#");
>               window.location.href = path[0];
>           }

If you are using the relative path try setting window.location.pathname, or set window.location.href to the full path and split is used to avoid # in URL.